# I need to determine value using LINQ to XML query?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, xml, linq

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<MYROOT>
  <Group name="G1">
      <Skill name="G1Skill1">
              <SubSkill>G1skill1sub1</SubSkill>
              <SubSkill>G1skill1sub2</SubSkill>
      </Skill >
    <Skill name="G1Skill2">
              <SubSkill>G1skill2sub1</SubSkill>
              <SubSkill>G1skill2sub2</SubSkill>
      </Skill >
  </Group>
  <Group name="G2">
    <Skill name="G2Skill1">
              <SubSkill>G2skill1sub1</SubSkill>
              <SubSkill>G2skill1sub2</SubSkill>
    </Skill >
    <Skill name="G2Skill2">
              <SubSkill>G2skill2sub1</SubSkill>
              <SubSkill>G2skill2sub2</SubSkill>
    </Skill >
 </Group>
</MYROOT>
```

For e.g . 
Inputs are `"G1"` & `"G1skill1sub1"`

Expected output = `G1Skill1` (Using single LINQ to XML)

I tried this code :

```
  var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("XMLFile1.xml"));
        var skills =
        from skill in xmlDoc.Descendants("Group")
        where skill.Attribute("name").Value.Equals("G1") // && skill.Element("SubSkill").Value.Equals("Group")
        select new
            {
                Myskill = skill.Element("Skill").Value,
                mytext= skill.Attribute("name").Value,
            };
```

But don't get proper output .

Comment: XPath is your friend. See [`XPathSelectElements`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342176.aspx) and friends.

Comment: @pst: Personally I prefer using LINQ to XML query expressions directly - XPath makes me nervous, as you end up combining code ("find descendants, compare for equality" etc and data "G1", "G1skill1sub1" etc). The fact that it's all just a string means there's no compile-time support, too - it's easier to end up with a syntax error which will only show up at execution time.

Comment: @Jon Skeet Unit tests ;-) I can see how it *could* lead to more chance for mistakes, but I've been bitten enough simply by forgetting to check an Attribute for null before use or getting a name wrong so... it's a little bit different than a more strongly-typed LINQ provider.

Comment: @pst: Just use a cast instead of using `.Value`, and nullity isn't a problem generally. Yes, it doesn't *eliminate* other problems such as names - but it *reduces* them. Also, using LINQ to XML means only learning an extra *library* rather than a whole (if small) *language*. Oh, and I find the LINQ to XML namespace support simpler :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use:

```
var skills = from group in doc.Descendants("Group")
             where (string) group.Attribute("name") == "G1"
             from subskill in group.Descendants("SubSkill")
             where (string) subskill == "G1skill1sub1"
             select (string) subskill.Parent.Attribute("name");
```

That's going by your inputs and expected output:

- Find all matching groups
- Find all matching subskills within those groups
- For each matching subskill, find the name of the parent (skill)

Comment: hey it is giving some expression like `System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2[<>f__AnonymousType0`2[System.Xml.Linq.XElement,System.Xml.Linq.XElement],System.String] `
as a output yes output value is there when I did `QuickWatch` it is there in result views > [0] > 'myoutput'
but how can I print that??

Comment: @ashuthinks: Iterate over `skills` - it implements `IEnumerable<string>`.

Comment: @ashuthinks: No, please elaborate on how you're trying to use it and what error you're getting... You should be able to do something like: `foreach (string x in skills) { Console.WriteLine(x); }`

Answer (score 0):

I tried like this and working fine

```
         string input1 = "G1";
        string input2 = "G1skill1sub1";

        string output =
            (from skill in xdoc.Descendants("Skill")
             let subskill = skill.Element("SubSkill")
             let g = skill.Parent
             where g.Name == "Group" && g.Attribute("name").Value == input1
             && subskill != null && subskill.Value == input2
             select skill.Attribute("name").Value).FirstOrDefault();

        Console.WriteLine(output);
```